# Can I tell search to check my Dropbox folder?

Tags: 22.04, lts, search, dropbox

Currently, the Meta key (for me it's the "Windows" key) toggles a screen that shows all my open windows and a search box.

[image]

That search box will find directories deeply nested in in `/home/Documents` and `/home/Videos` but it's skipping `/home/Dropbox` -- I looked at the Search settings and I don't see anyway to tell the system search to please also search Dropbox.

How do I tell it to search Dropbox?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure there is and I can't find any extension for it either but instead of using `Super` for the Activities Overview I use the search engine in `Files` Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In "Settings", go to the "Search" pane.
- In the top bar, click "Search locations" [image: screenshot of "search pane"]
- It might be in the "Bookmarks" tab, if you've bookmarked it.
  [image: Screenshot of Search Locations modal]
- Otherwise, on the "Other" tab, click `+` and select the "Dropbox" folder in the file picker dialog that appears.

Comment:  I looked and looked for some kind of tab. But missed that entirely.

Comment: I also find the current place to set this not logical. "Search locations" only applies to the "Files" search engine, so does not belong on top, suggesting it applies to all engines.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it from console. If you're up to doing a [little bit of coding](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation)... Open a terminal.

Make sure you have the `jq` tool installed:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Create the necessary token and keys [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps).

- Click create app, name it, choose **'scoped app'** for the type.
- Create a text file. Save your **app id**, **app secret** and the **generated token** for reference.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

search_value="$1"
refresh_token="<YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN>"
app_key="<YOUR_APP_KEY>"
app_secret="<YOUR_APP_SECRET>"

# Refresh the access token
access_token=$(curl -s https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token \
    -d grant_type=refresh_token \
    -d refresh_token="$refresh_token" \
    -u "$app_key":"$app_secret" | jq -r .access_token)

# Search for files
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/search_v2 \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Dropbox-Api-Path-Root: ' \
  --data "{\"query\":\"$search_value\",\"options\":{},\"match_field_options\":{\"include_highlights\":true},\"include_highlights\":true}"

exit 0
```

Save as: `dropbox_search.sh`
Change mode executable: `chmod +x dropbox_search.sh`
Usage: `./dropbox_search.sh "Your search query here"`